# Why isn't source transformation working here?

Tags: power, current-source, voltage-source

[image]

Doing it normally you would get the answer of 2320 mW (a 4 V drop across the current source).

However, for this question I had done a source transformation to a 1 V source,
then I added the two sources to become 25 V (to me it goes (-1 V+)---(-24 V+) in series so I can add it) and found the power by 25<sup>2</sup>/125 = 5 W (for this particular question: 2500 mW).

I do not know how I am messing up my source transformation or if I can even use source transformation here. This is a 1st year introduction to electronics problem in my college.

Comment: I agree with the 4 volts figure but I'm failing to see how you get 2320 mW

Comment: @Andyaka P=V*I, for current source that will be -4x40x10E-3 (minus because voltage and current are in opposite direction) and for voltage source you will have a 0.2Amps through it making it 24*0.2. Making it 4.8-0.16 = 4.64. Half of that is 2.32W